# Checking the checkbox in recyclerview from a different activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-checkbox

[Asking question for the first time on Stack Overflow] 
I am making an application where the user will be shown with a list of locations in a recyclerView. RecyclerView has generic rows and each row has a cardview in which there is a checkbox and a textview. When the user clicks on a row, he is re-directed to a different activity where they are supposed to answer certain questions and click on save. Once clicked save, he will be re-directed to previous activity and I need that particular location's checkbox to be checked.

How can I do this?

Thanks for the help and sorry if I explained it badly.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow. Have you read through the android documentation found here:https://developer.android.com/guide/ you are going to want to read through the activity and adapter sections of that. Also you can refer to a summarized version here https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#attaching-event-handlers-within-adapter

There are many ways to accomplish what you are asking. Sounds like you are looking for `startActivityForResult()` this method simply takes an intent and says "hey when that activity is finished I want some information back so I can do something with the result"

When you want to pass a result back to your calling activity in this case, you will need to set some data before you finish the created activity like so

```
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("location", selectedLocation);
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

By doing this you can receive the result in your calling activity with the method implementation of `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`

In your case lets say a user taps a card and you start the new activity using `startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)` when the user is done with this activity and the activity is going to finish you want to set some outstate data using the Intent data passing method I showed above. Maybe you want to send the location back. Simply attach the location as an extra and receive it in your `onActivityResult()` implementation and then make the appropriate changes in that view based on the data. Hope that helps.

In the future, it always helps to provide example code with your question. It will help users better assist you on your issue and more importantly make users want to help you out. You seem new to android development so make sure to read through the android docs whenever you can to better your understanding of android as a whole. Cheers!